# How to stop a function in python?

Tags: python, function, click

I want to stop the function so I can run a different one, this is my code:

```
from pynput import keyboard
import os, sys
import pygame
import time
from pygame import mixer
from pynput import mouse
from pygame import mixer
pygame.mixer.init(buffer=10)
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

def click0():
    def on_press(key):
        print("HARD CLICK")

def click1():
    def on_press(key):
        print("MEM CLICK")

def click2():
    def on_press(key):
        print("SOFT CLICK")


# Collect events until released
with Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()

while True:
    click0()
    time.sleep(1) #sleep for 1 second
    click1()
    time.sleep(2) #sleep for 1 second
    click2()
```

I want it to be like this:

```
from pynput import keyboard
import os, sys
import pygame
import time
from pygame import mixer
from pynput import mouse
from pygame import mixer
pygame.mixer.init(buffer=10)
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

def click0():
    def on_press(key):
        print("HARD CLICK")

def click1():
    def on_press(key):
        print("MEM CLICK")

def click2():
    def on_press(key):
        print("SOFT CLICK")


# Collect events until released
with Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()

while True:
    click0()
    time.sleep(1) #sleep for 1 second
    click0(quit)
    click1()
    time.sleep(2) #sleep for 1 second
    click1(quit)
    click2()
```

So I want to code the have 3 funcstions and it loops taking turns like: click1 (IS LOOPING), click2 (IS LOOPING), click3 (IS LOOPING), click1 (IS LOOPING), click..

But I want to stop the funcstion before running a diffent one like: click1 (IS LOOPING), click1 (STOPPED) click2 (IS LOOPING), click2 (STOPPED) click3 (IS LOOPING), click3 (STOPPED) click..
Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the async & return operators:

```py
async def click0():
  #.. do things
  return 

async def click1():
  #.. do things again
  return 

async def main():
  while True:
      await click0()
      await click1()
```

This await method essentially waits till a function is finish before moving onto the next line, so here the click0 function will need to complete before click1() executes,

alternatively, you can call click1 from click0, and click2 from click1 and so on...